# Mapear Id de um model em outro sem aparecer um DropDownList

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tive um problema ao fazer relacionamentos em minha aplicação. meu projeto é de uma escola, e nele tenho que ter as ocorrências. Mas na hora de relacionar o Aluno com a Ocorrência me aconteceu que, na view create das ocorrências, me aparece um dropdownlist com os alunos cadastrados, pra que faça o relacionamento, ou seja, mapeie a ocorrência no aluno, digo, o que o aluno aprontou. O que eu queria na verdade, era que, quando eu carregasse os detalhes do aluno, tivesse um collapse(tipo accordion) onde o usuário pudesse colocar a ocorrência para aquele aluno em específico, pegando o Id dele, ou seja, passando o id do aluno na view detalhes e o mesmo id do aluno pro mapeamento certinho da ocorrência. Ou seja, cadastrasse a ocorrência para aquele aluno, e que não seja carregado um dropdaownlist com os alunos.

Vou colocar aqui, a view de cadastro do aluno pra ver o que se pode fazer:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
     {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Ocorrencia</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tipo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tipo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tipo)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Causa, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Causa)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Causa)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Observacao, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Observacao)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Observacao)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlunoId, "AlunoId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("AlunoId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlunoId)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Aqui a parte do controller que popula o dropdownlist:

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var ocorrencias = db.Ocorrencias.Include(o => o.Aluno);
        return View(ocorrencias.ToList());
    }

    // GET: /Ocorrencias/Detalhes/5
    public ActionResult Detalhes(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Ocorrencia ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencias.Find(id);
        if (ocorrencia == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }

    // GET: /Ocorrencias/Adiciona
    public ActionResult Adiciona()
    {
        ViewBag.AlunoId = new SelectList(db.Alunos, "Id", "Nome");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Ocorrencias/Adiciona
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you            want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Adiciona([Bind(Include="Id,Tipo,Causa,Observacao,AlunoId")]    Ocorrencia ocorrencia)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Ocorrencias.Add(ocorrencia);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.AlunoId = new SelectList(db.Alunos, "Id", "Nome", ocorrencia.AlunoId);
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }

    // GET: /Ocorrencias/Edita/5
    public ActionResult Edita(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Ocorrencia ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencias.Find(id);
        if (ocorrencia == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.AlunoId = new SelectList(db.Alunos, "Id", "Nome", ocorrencia.AlunoId);
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }

    // POST: /Ocorrencias/Edita/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edita([Bind(Include="Id,Tipo,Causa,Observacao,AlunoId")] Ocorrencia ocorrencia)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(ocorrencia).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.AlunoId = new SelectList(db.Alunos, "Id", "Nome", ocorrencia.AlunoId);
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }

    // GET: /Ocorrencias/Remove/5
    public ActionResult Remove(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Ocorrencia ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencias.Find(id);
        if (ocorrencia == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }

    // POST: /Ocorrencias/Remove/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Remove")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(long id)
    {
        Ocorrencia ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencias.Find(id);
        db.Ocorrencias.Remove(ocorrencia);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

E aqui o que eu coloquei no model de ALunos, que faz a carga do nomes dos aluno aparecerem no dropdownlist:

```
    public ICollection<Ocorrencia> Ocorrencias { get; set; }
    public Aluno()
    {
        this.Ocorrencias = new HashSet<Ocorrencia>();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só trocar:

```cs
@Html.DropDownList("AlunoId", String.Empty)
```

Por:

```cs
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AlunoId)
<div>@model.Aluno.Nome</div>
```

### Controller

```cs
public ActionResult AdicionarOcorrencia(int id)
{
    var aluno = db.Alunos.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
    return View(aluno);
}
```

Comment: E no meu controler e model de Aluno ? Eu trocaria os termos também ? Vou editar as perguntas e colocar o que tem no controller e no model, que eu acho que foi pelo que eu coloquei que gerou essa lista !

Comment: Não precisa trocar nada no `Model`, só que seu `Controller` vai ter que inicializar o `Aluno`. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: E o Icollection no model Aluno, tem algum problema ? Não né ?

Comment: O de Ocorrências? Não. Usa normal.

Comment: Não não, no model de Alunos que ta ali em cima, que tem o ICollection, o de ocorrências num precisa mexer não. To falando no de aluno, eu trocaria o ICollection por Ocorrência Id e Ocorrência ?

Comment: Aí você teria que usar o `Html.BeginCollectionItem` pra iterar a coleção de Ocorrências, como eu tinha te falado anteriormente. Aí acho que vale a pena abrir outra pergunta.

Comment: É porque eu não queria fazer um dropdown, eu queria que a ocorrência ficasse vinculada ao aluno. Pelo que eu entendi, quando faço um ICollection, eu faço uma lista que pode ser populada em um dropdown. Eu num queria isso, eu queria vincular a ocorrência ao aluno, digo o Id do aluno. Ai nesse caso seria uma relação de 1:N. Ou seja, um aluno pra várias ocorrências.

Comment: Então, como eu disse, abra uma nova pergunta que eu te ensino a fazer.

Comment: Uma pergunta sobre esse relacionamento ? Digo, estou perdido em como abrir uma nova pergunta. Vou fazer uma com o título de como usar o Html.BeginCollectionItem, Ok ? Pode ser ?

Comment: Aqui cigano o link da pergunta que eu acabei de fazer [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15804/duvida-em-relacionamento)

Comment: Cigano, vou precisar de uma ajudinha no controller. Tentei fazer essa implementação que você indicou, mas não deu certo deu erro. Seria nessa pergunta, ou na outra ?

Comment: Coloque o erro na outra, por favor.

Comment: Vou colocar o Controller todo pode ser ?

Comment: Tranquilo. Pode colocar.

Comment: Ok, colocado lá !