# É possível enviar uma lista de objectos do javascript para uma função no contoller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estou a retornar uma lista de dados de um tipo de objecto (GAR) da função `actualizarGARs` do controller:

```
var listaGARTratadas = db.GAR.ToList();
return Json(listaGARTratadas);
```

E no javascript queria enviar esta lista de objectos novamente para uma outra função (`carregaGARsCriadas`):

```
$.getJSON("/GAR/actualizarGARs", { carimbo: carimbo, CaixaFisicaGAR: $("#CaixaFisicaGAR").val() },
  function (result) {
        $("#divListagemGARActualizadas").empty();
        $("#divListagemGARActualizadas").load("/GAR/carregaGARsCriadas", {garsCriadas: result});
}
```

Onde recebo esta lista de objectos passados no `result`:

```
public ActionResult carregaGARsCriadas(List<GAR> garsCriadas) {
        return PartialView("listaGARsCriadas");
    }
```

O problema é que recebo a variável `garsCriadas` com o número correto de elementos no objecto (por exemplo 5), mas o **conteúdo de cada elemento fica a null**

Comment: Conhece o `BeginCollectionItem`? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15804/d%C3%BAvida-em-constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-view-e-controller-com-entidade-dependente-de-cardinalida/15809#15809

Comment: O que tem no `result`?

Comment: O `result` tem uma lista de dados do tipo `GAR`. Se eu fizer um `.each` com o `result`, os dados estão lá. O que queria era passar esta lista para a função `carregaGARsCriadas`

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, estive a dar uma vista de olhos mas penso que não seja o que quero. Eu no `.getJson` para a função `/GAR/actualizarGARs` estou a tratar dados, só meti `var listaGARTratadas = db.GAR.ToList();` para simplificar a pergunta

Comment: @CesarMiguel Se está produzindo 5 objetos com valores nulos de propriedades, significa que o `ModelBinder`está se perdendo na hora de criar os objetos com os valores. Por isso o `BeginCollectionItem`. Ele resolve exatamente esta parte.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, eu ainda não estou a colocar os dados na partial. Logo na minha função `carregaGARsCriadas` verifico que a lista de objectos passados no `.load` vem de forma errada. Por exemplo, em vez de receber um elemento com os dados: `["idGAR: 12", "SerieGAR:19", etc etc]` recebo `["idGAR: 0", "SerieGAR:null", etc etc]`

Comment: Entendi. Já adianto que não tem resposta fácil, pois você precisa serializar um objeto que já foi desseralizado.

Comment: Sim, até faz sentido que o objecto tenha sido desseralizado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei à minha questão passa por criar um array com todos os id's que quero passar para a função no controller, em vez de estar a passar uma lista de objectos.

Construí então o array no javascript:

```
$.getJSON("/GAR/actualizarGARs", { carimbo: carimbo, CaixaFisicaGAR: $("#CaixaFisicaGAR").val() },
        function (result) {                
            var lista = "[";
            var len = result.length;
            $.each(result, function (index, itemData) {
                if (index == len - 1) {
                    lista += "" + itemData.IdGar + "";
                } else {
                    lista += "" + itemData.IdGar + ",";
                }
            });
            lista += "]";

            $("#divListagemGARActualizadas").load("/GAR/carregaGARsCriadas", { garsCriadas: lista });

        });
```

Assim a variável `lista` fica com o conteúdo `[2001, 2002, 3500]` por exemplo. Da parte do controller recebi esta `lista` como `string` e fiz um `split` por `,`:

```
 public ActionResult carregaGARsCriadas(string garsCriadas)
 {
    if (!(garsCriadas.Contains("undefined")))
    {
       var arrayGARs = garsCriadas.Trim(new char[] { '[', ']' }).Split(',').Select(a => int.Parse(a)).ToList();//.Split
       var listaGARs = db.GAR.Where(g => arrayGARs.Contains(g.IdGar)).ToList();
       return PartialView("listaGARsCriadas", listaGARs);
     }
     return PartialView("listaGARsCriadas");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Voce pode trabalhar com arrays em javascript. Monta o array na sua view e depois passa para o controller. No controller abre o array. ;)

Comment: Marcelo, não é recomendado o uso de respostas com links. Pois nada garante que o link continuará lá com o conteúdo. O recomendado é colocar um sumário do que está no link e colocar a referência caso alguém queira saber mais.